# Show progress half way in li using css

Tags: html, css, less, linear-gradients, radial-gradients

[image]

Something like below:

[image]

My Less looks as below at the moment.

```
    /*progressbar*/
.progressbar {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    counter-reset: step;
    clear: both;
}

.progressbar li {
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 24%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;

    &:before {
    content: counter(step);
    counter-increment: step;
    width: 25px;
    line-height: 13px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: transparent;
    border: 6px solid #ececec ;
    background: #27ae60 ;
    border-radius: 19px;
    margin: 0 auto 4px;
    }

    &:after {
    content: '';
    width: 85%;
    height: 3px;
    background: #B9B9B9;
    position: absolute;
    left: -42%;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 0;
   }

   &:first-child:after {
    content: none; 
  }
}

.progress-payment li {
    width: 50%;
}

.progressbar li.active{
    &:after, &:before {      
    background: @success-btn;
    color: @success-btn;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Order Placed</li>
    <li>Shipped</li>
    <li>Completed</li>
    <li>Settled</li>
</ul>
```

Please help

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle for it.

Comment: or add your html code here.

Comment: @JeetDaloneboy Added html

Comment: http://codepen.io/michaelmcqueen/pen/GdroF check this out.

Comment: @JeetDaloneboy how does this answer my question?

Comment: well your question it self is not clear please briefly describe your question and also your code you have done till now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by using a `linear-gradient` background for the pseudo element that is producing the bar. The gradient is half-and-half, with *completed color* for first half and the *pending color* for rest.

```css
/*progressbar*/

.progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  counter-reset: step;
  clear: both;
  list-style: none;
}
.progressbar li {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 24%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: transparent;
  border: 6px solid #ececec;
  background: #27ae60;
  border-radius: 19px;
  margin: 0 auto 4px;
}
.progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 85%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #B9B9B9;
  position: absolute;
  left: -42%;
  top: 17px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}
.progress-payment li {
  width: 50%;
}
.progressbar li.active:after,
.progressbar li.active:before {
  background: #27ae60;
  color: white;
}

.progressbar li.complete:after {
  background: #27ae60;
}
.progressbar li.half-complete:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #27ae60 50%, #B9B9B9 50%);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="progressbar">
  <li class="complete">Order Placed</li>
  <li class="complete">Shipped</li>
  <li class="active">Completed</li>
  <li class="half-complete">Settled</li>
</ul>
```

---

If you want a slightly ***curved half-fill*** for the progress bar then you could use `radial-gradient` for the background like in the below snippet.

```css
/*progressbar*/

.progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  counter-reset: step;
  clear: both;
  list-style: none;
}
.progressbar li {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 24%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: transparent;
  border: 6px solid #ececec;
  background: #27ae60;
  border-radius: 19px;
  margin: 0 auto 4px;
}
.progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 85%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #B9B9B9;
  position: absolute;
  left: -42%;
  top: 17px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}
.progress-payment li {
  width: 50%;
}
.progressbar li.active:after,
.progressbar li.active:before {
  background: #27ae60;
  color: white;
}

.progressbar li.complete:after {
  background: #27ae60;
}
.progressbar li.half-complete:after {
  background: radial-gradient(50% 300% at 25% 50%, #27ae60 50%, #B9B9B9 40%);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="progressbar">
  <li class="complete">Order Placed</li>
  <li class="complete">Shipped</li>
  <li class="active">Completed</li>
  <li class="half-complete">Settled</li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** Both the solutions assume that your [target browsers are those that support gradients](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) (IE10+).

Comment: @vini - please note that accepting an answer is not enough to award the bounty, You need to do so explicitly.

Comment: Done sorry got late :)

Comment: @vini: That's ok. No worries :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `animation` for this.

Since you are already using both pseudoelements in your list items. We will use a pseudoelement in the `ul` element to provide the empty progress line.

We will keep your other classes just for demo purposes but you can optimize this method way further. The principle would have to change to take into consideration the whole process from 0 to 100% from step 1 to 4, not to 1 to 2, 2 to 3, etc.

Here we go:

First we create our pseudoelement in the `ul` element just for the grey fallback.

```
.progressbar::after {
  content: '';
  width: 68%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #B9B9B9;
  position: absolute;
  left: 17%;
  top: 17px;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

---

Then we scale down the `::after` pseudoelement of the list item to 0 in the main axis. *(use one `:` if you are providing older browser support)*.

Here we are keeping your class just as a selector, like I previously said you can make this even better but it would require changing some logic.

Here we also declare an animation we will create in the next step. **What will it do?** It will just `scale` back to 1 our pseudoelement.

```
.progressbar li.half-complete:after {
  transform: scaleX(0);
  color: white;
  animation: fill 100ms linear forwards;
  background-color: #27ae60;
}
```

We define the keyframe:

```
@keyframes fill {
  to {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

So far we get this:

```css
/*progressbar*/

.progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  counter-reset: step;
  clear: both;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
.progressbar li {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 24%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: transparent;
  border: 6px solid #ececec;
  background: #27ae60;
  border-radius: 19px;
  margin: 0 auto 4px;
}
.progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 85%;
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -42%;
  top: 17px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.progressbar::after {
  content: '';
  width: 68%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #B9B9B9;
  position: absolute;
  left: 17%;
  top: 17px;
  z-index: -2;
}
.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}
.progress-payment li {
  width: 50%;
}
.progressbar li.active:after,
.progressbar li.active:before {
  background: #27ae60;
  color: white;
}
.progressbar li.half-complete:before {
  color: white;
}
.progressbar li.complete:after {
  background: #27ae60;
}
.progressbar li.half-complete:after {
  transform: scaleX(0);
  color: white;
  animation: fill 3s linear forwards;
  background-color: #27ae60;
}
@keyframes fill {
  to {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="progressbar">
  <li class="complete">Order Placed</li>
  <li class="complete">Shipped</li>
  <li class="active">Completed</li>
  <li class="half-complete">Settled</li>
</ul>
```

We are not quite there yet, we got the animation, but it starts from the center and we want a specific frame, when the bar is at 50%.

Since the browser creates multiple frames when you create an animation, you can get the one you want with the property `animation-delay`, normally you would use a positive value, but when you use a negative one, the animation starts from that point.

Lets make the animation start from the left with `transform-origin: left` and finish all the way to the right without using `animation-delay` yet:

```css
/*progressbar*/

.progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  counter-reset: step;
  clear: both;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
.progressbar li {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 24%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: transparent;
  border: 6px solid #ececec;
  background: #27ae60;
  border-radius: 19px;
  margin: 0 auto 4px;
}
.progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 85%;
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -42%;
  top: 17px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.progressbar::after {
  content: '';
  width: 68%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #B9B9B9;
  position: absolute;
  left: 17%;
  top: 17px;
  z-index: -2;
}
.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}
.progress-payment li {
  width: 50%;
}
.progressbar li.active:after,
.progressbar li.active:before {
  background: #27ae60;
  color: white;
}
.progressbar li.half-complete:before {
  color: white;
}
.progressbar li.complete:after {
  background: #27ae60;
}
.progressbar li.half-complete:after {
  transform: scaleX(0);
  color: white;
  animation: fill 3s linear forwards;
  transform-origin: left;
  background-color: #27ae60;
}
@keyframes fill {
  to {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="progressbar">
  <li class="complete">Order Placed</li>
  <li class="complete">Shipped</li>
  <li class="active">Completed</li>
  <li class="half-complete">Settled</li>
</ul>
```

Now using an `animation-delay` with a negative value:

```css
/*progressbar*/

.progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  counter-reset: step;
  clear: both;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
.progressbar li {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 24%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: transparent;
  border: 6px solid #ececec;
  background: #27ae60;
  border-radius: 19px;
  margin: 0 auto 4px;
}
.progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 85%;
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -42%;
  top: 17px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.progressbar::after {
  content: '';
  width: 68%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #B9B9B9;
  position: absolute;
  left: 17%;
  top: 17px;
  z-index: -2;
}
.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}
.progress-payment li {
  width: 50%;
}
.progressbar li.active:after,
.progressbar li.active:before {
  background: #27ae60;
  color: white;
}
.progressbar li.half-complete:before {
  color: white;
}
.progressbar li.complete:after {
  background: #27ae60;
}
.progressbar li.half-complete:after {
  transform: scaleX(0);
  color: white;
  animation: fill 3s linear forwards;
  transform-origin: left;
  animation-delay: -1.5s;
  background-color: #27ae60;
}
@keyframes fill {
  to {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="progressbar">
  <li class="complete">Order Placed</li>
  <li class="complete">Shipped</li>
  <li class="active">Completed</li>
  <li class="half-complete">Settled</li>
</ul>
```

Since the total duration of the animation in the demo is `3s` you just use half that as a negative value to get the 50%, see how the animation starts from there.

Then we just use `animation-play-state: paused;` to prevent the transition.

```css
/*progressbar*/

.progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  counter-reset: step;
  clear: both;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
.progressbar li {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 24%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: transparent;
  border: 6px solid #ececec;
  background: #27ae60;
  border-radius: 19px;
  margin: 0 auto 4px;
}
.progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 85%;
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -42%;
  top: 17px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.progressbar::after {
  content: '';
  width: 68%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #B9B9B9;
  position: absolute;
  left: 17%;
  top: 17px;
  z-index: -2;
}
.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}
.progress-payment li {
  width: 50%;
}
.progressbar li.active:after,
.progressbar li.active:before {
  background: #27ae60;
  color: white;
}
.progressbar li.half-complete:before {
  color: white;
}
.progressbar li.complete:after {
  background: #27ae60;
}
.progressbar li.half-complete:after {
  transform: scaleX(0);
  color: white;
  animation: fill 3s linear forwards;
  transform-origin: left;
  animation-delay: -1.5s;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  background-color: #27ae60;
}
@keyframes fill {
  to {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="progressbar">
  <li class="complete">Order Placed</li>
  <li class="complete">Shipped</li>
  <li class="active">Completed</li>
  <li class="half-complete">Settled</li>
</ul>
```

We can then clean it a little bit and in this demo we use some javascript to see how this can be manipulated:

```
.progressbar li.half-complete:after {
  transform: scaleX(0);
  color: white;
  animation: fill 100ms linear forwards; /* Use an easier value to represent percentages in a progress bar*/
  transform-origin: left;
  animation-delay: inherit; /* We inherit the animation-delay from the `li` element, which we can easily manipulate with javascript*/
  animation-play-state: paused;
  background-color: #27ae60;
}
```

---

### Final Result:

```js
var progress = document.getElementById("progress");

var progressBarLastItem = document.querySelector(".progressbar li:last-child");

progress.addEventListener("change", function() {
  progressBarLastItem.style.animationDelay = "-" + this.value + "ms";
});
```

```css
/*progressbar*/

.progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  counter-reset: step;
  clear: both;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
.progressbar li {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 24%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: transparent;
  border: 6px solid #ececec;
  background: #27ae60;
  border-radius: 19px;
  margin: 0 auto 4px;
}
.progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 85%;
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -42%;
  top: 17px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.progressbar::after {
  content: '';
  width: 68%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #B9B9B9;
  position: absolute;
  left: 17%;
  top: 17px;
  z-index: -2;
}
.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}
.progress-payment li {
  width: 50%;
}
.progressbar li.active:after,
.progressbar li.active:before {
  background: #27ae60;
  color: white;
}
.progressbar li.half-complete:before {
  color: white;
}
.progressbar li.complete:after {
  background: #27ae60;
}
.progressbar li.half-complete:after {
  transform: scaleX(0);
  color: white;
  animation: fill 100ms linear forwards;
  transform-origin: left;
  animation-delay: inherit;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  background-color: #27ae60;
}
@keyframes fill {
  to {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="progressbar">
  <li class="complete">Order Placed</li>
  <li class="complete">Shipped</li>
  <li class="active">Completed</li>
  <li class="half-complete">Settled</li>
</ul>

<input id="progress" type="range" min="0" max="100">
```